# All dates between the given range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on leave tracker using mysql as database.

I have two columns from and to date. I don't want anyone to apply leave on the already applied dates. how to write query for that.

[image]

This is the query I have written, but it does not produce the required output:

```
SELECT *
FROM `taken_leave_tracker`
WHERE emp_id = '135835'
  and (taken_to_date  <= '2017-02-02')
  and (taken_from_date >= '2017-02-01')
```

Please help to write query.

Comment: According to the image your table has the columns applied_from_date and applied_to_date, but your query includes the columns taken_to_date and taken_from_date.

Comment: Actually there are two kind of leaves applied and taken. Mistakenly I took screenshot of applied leave table. Though the question I am asking could be answered on either table.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your variable is called `date`, you need to execute the following query

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `taken_leave_tracker` 
WHERE emp_id = '135835' AND date >= applied_from_date AND date <= applied_to_date;
```

Based on count value, you can write the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You rather should be comparing the range on a single column

```
WHERE emp_id = '135835'
  and (taken_from_date >= '2017-02-01' and taken_from_date  <= '2017-02-02')
```